# Drop-down values

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I got two php files the Add.php and Edit.php

In Add.php. A drop-down list of date and gender.

```
 <tr>
    <td width="400" id="caption" style="text-align:right;">Birthdate</td>
 <td>
    <select id="monthID" name="month">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>

    <select id="dayID" name="day">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>

    <select id="yearID" name="year">
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="400" id="caption" style="text-align:right;">Gender</td>
    <td id="caption" style="text-align:left;">
        <select name="gender">
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If I choose April 3 2010 and Female in the drop-downs. And insert it in my table_1

```
Assume this are drop-downs

                  Birthdate: April 3 2010 
                  Gender:    Female
```

Now, when I want to update the record(s) in Edit.php the drop-down value should be also the same

```
                  Birthdate: April 3 2010 
                  Gender:    Female
```

But instead it gives me this

```
                  Birthdate: January 1 2013
                  Gender:    Male
```

- It seems like a default value whenever I visit in Edit.php. (January 1 2013 Male - are the first items in the dropdowns)

How can I make [April 23 2013 Female] appear in my drop-down Instead of the first values that I didn't choose.

Thanks and sorry for the title I can't think for a good title for this.

Comment: I almost forgot... it composed of 4 drop-downs
month, day, year and gender are all drop-downs. 

-> Birthday and gender <-

Comment: Could you post your PHP / SQL Code?

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement to compare each value with your record and then add "selected" to this option

Answer (score 0):

here is the basic concept hope you catch the idea

```
<?php
$array = array(1=>"January",
2=>"February",
3=>"March",
4=>"April",
5=>"May",
6=>"June",
7=>"July",
8=>"August",
9=>"September",
10=>"October",
11=>"November",
12=>"December");

$stored_data = "2";


foreach($array as $key => $val) {

    if($stored_data == $key) {

        echo "<option value='$key' selected='1'>$val</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='$key'>$val</option>";

    }
}
?>
```